# Getting MODULE_NOT_FOUND when trying to install node.js on windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I installed node js for windows ,i set the PATH Environment variables to C:\Program Files\nodejs and C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm (among with the existing Git paths ..).
And restarted my computer.

When i test node.js it seems to be fine and returns :
node -v
v5.3.0

but when i try npm -v it runs into an error.

this is my error log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok

1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'prefix',
1 verbose cli   '-g' ]
2 info using npm@3.3.12
3 info using node@v5.3.0
4 verbose stack Error: Cannot find module 'npm-autoinit/autoinit'
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
4 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
4 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
4 verbose stack     at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:288:9)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:384:16
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:80:7
4 verbose stack     at Array.forEach (native)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:79:13
4 verbose stack     at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:17:25)
5 verbose cwd C:\Users\Cheli
6 error Windows_NT 10.0.10586
7 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "prefix" "-g"
8 error node v5.3.0
9 error npm  v3.3.12
10 error code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
11 error Cannot find module 'npm-autoinit/autoinit'
12 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
12 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
13 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: have you tried updating npm yet? MS wrote a tool to do it automatically apparently: https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade

Comment: Thanks , but i tried that still doesn't work :(